# Pegar id do ultimo registro inserido no banco

Tags: android, sqlite

Queria saber se tem como eu inserir um registro no banco e ja retorna o id deste registro em android sqlite

uso este metodo para inserir

```
public boolean insertH(HistoricoObjeto historico) {

    /* Mapa com a coluna e os valores de cada coluna. */
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("datahora", historico.getDatahora());
    values.put("mensagem", historico.getMensagem());


    /* Executa um insert no banco de dados usando o mapa de valores. */
    /* Retorna -1 caso ocorra algum erro no INSERT. */
    long retorno = this.banco.insert("historico", null, values);

    if(retorno != -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid

Comment: Já pensou em fazer uma query retornando o ultimo registro inserido por ordem descrescente.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM    TABLE
WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem, na verdade, a classe `SQLiteDatabase` tem seu próprio método de inserção que retorna o `ID` da linha recém-criado. Penso que esta é a melhor maneira de obter o novo `ID`. Você pode verificar sua documentação:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public long insertH(HistoricoObjeto historico) {

/* Mapa com a coluna e os valores de cada coluna. */
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("datahora", historico.getDatahora());
values.put("mensagem", historico.getMensagem());


/* Executa um insert no banco de dados usando o mapa de valores. */
/* Retorna -1 caso ocorra algum erro no INSERT. */
long retorno = this.banco.insert("historico", null, values);
return retorno;
}
```

este retorno fica com o id no ultimo histórico inserido